SDL2 Window won't show
I am trying to follow a tutorial that creates a blank window that can be closed using the Esc button, but the window never shows. This is on WSL running Ubuntu 20.05.6
The code compiles and runs without errors, but once it runs it doesn't really do anything. There's no icon on the taskbar or anything like that.
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        bool Initialize();
        void RunLoop();
        void Shutdown();
    private:
        void ProcessInput();
        void UpdateGame();
        void GenerateOutput();

        SDL_Window* mWindow;
        bool mIsRunning;
};

#endif

Game.h - This is the header file with the function declarations
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

Game::Game() {
    this->mWindow = nullptr;
    this->mIsRunning = true;
}

bool Game::Initialize() {
    int sdlResult = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if(sdlResult != 0) {
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Test",
        100,
        100,
        1024,
        768,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );
    if(!mWindow) {
        SDL_Log("Failed to create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }

    return true;
}

void Game::Shutdown() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::RunLoop() {
    while(mIsRunning) {
        ProcessInput();
        UpdateGame();
        GenerateOutput();
    }
}

void Game::ProcessInput() {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch(event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            mIsRunning = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    const Uint8* state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE]) {
        mIsRunning = false;
    }
}

void Game::UpdateGame() {}
void Game::GenerateOutput() {}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Game game;
    bool success = game.Initialize();
    if(success) {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        game.RunLoop();
    }
    game.Shutdown();
    return 0;
}

Game.cpp - This is the implementation of the Game class. UpdateGame() and GenerateOutput() are both empty because I haven't gotten that far in the tutorial yet.
The code doesn't output either of the error messages in the Initialize() method, so I'm assuming that the window is created, but not shown. Initially, I hadn't implemented the ProcessInput() method yet, but other questions on this site were resolved by adding an event loop, so I did as well, but it didn't change anything.  There is an error that states "Unknown pixel format" but after running the debugger, I traced it to an SDL function that creates a dummy mouse cursor and calls a function with parameters that will always cause it to fail, so I don't think it's relevant.
EDIT: The window showed up once I compiled and ran it in Windows rather than in WSL. I did have to define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED in Game.h, I believe it has something to do with overriding WinMain()

OT: Wouldn't it be easier, or at least more in line with the event processing loop, to not use SDL_GetKeyboardState, and instead use keyboard events?

Which X server are you using?

@genpfault I'm not actually running this on Ubuntu, it's on a Windows system with WSL so I'm not using X-server at all.

@Someprogrammerdude Maybe? I'm not very familiar with this library, so this is essentially just copy-pasted from a tutorial

How did you download SDL2? Using your package manager, or you built it from source? Also you could try doing it without WSL (since apps compiled in WSL can't be reasonably shared with other Windows users).

@HolyBlackCat I had to completely set up my entire environment on Windows but now the window does pop up. I did have to switch the main() to WinMain() instead but everything else stayed the same. I’m not sure how you would word it, but if you put this as an answer I will mark it as accepted

I don't think it deserves a full answer. Though if you had to use WinMain, it means you didn't use SDL2 how it's supposed to be used.

@HolyBlackCat You are correct, I looked at some other tutorials online and it runs through main() if I define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED before including the SDL2 library. I don't have any experience with SDL2 so I will likely have to Frankenstein tutorials together like this until I can get a grasp of what I'm doing

The intended approach (for better or worse) is to link against SDL2main.lib, then you need neither SDL_MAIN_HANDLED nor WinMain().
